# Is there anyway to call javascript function inside Rails view?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am wondering if there's a way to call a javascript function:

```
function get_url(link) {
  var url = window.location.href;
  var params = url.split('/')[3]
  return params == link ? 'active-menu' : ''
}

get_url('#about');
```

Inside rails views links like this:

```
<li class="nav-item">
     <%= link_to "About", root_path(:anchor => 'about'), class: "nav-link #{javascript(get_url('#about'))}", :"data-id" => "about" %>
</li>
```

Notice this part:

```
class: "nav-link #{javascript(get_url('#about'))}"
```

Is there a way to do this? If not, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Rails have nothing to do with this problem. So, basically, you want get JS to add some class to your `<a>` tag, right?

Comment: that function will make more sense in view (ruby) than javascript, if you just want to add class depending on url

Comment: @Qubis741 Basically I have three sets of menus. The other two menu set, I used normal rails helper methods such as `current_page?` and `request.fullpath` which works fine. Now that there is this `#` on the params, I need to use javascript instead for this particular type of menu. `localhost:3000/#contact` won't be called out by using regular server side rails helper such as `current_page?`. That's why I use `windows.location` instead.

Comment: **Yes you can run js in a rails view** - but its not going to help you in the least. You can run javascript on your server with `Node.js` or some other javascript runtime. But that code is not going to run since the js its not running in a browser. And its a fools errand to begin with since browsers do not send the hash component of a url to the server when making requests. It does not matter if you are running Rails, Node or the magical unicorn framework - you can't get the hash since it was not sent in the first place.

Comment: your whole problem is that you want to use rails link_to to make a non-standard link, why not use plain HTML <a onclick="jsfunc();"> and do whatever you want with it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can defer that function call to client-side scripts:

1. add a class to these menu elements so that you can easily fetch all these, for example `js-nav-link`
2. in js on dom content loaded calculate and add necessary classes:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  let hash = window.location.hash;
  if(!!hash){
    let activeMenu = document.querySelector(`.js-nav-link[data-id="${hash}"]`);
    if(activeMenu){
      activeMenu.classList.add('active-menu');
    }
  }
});
```

Also you might want to look more deeply into utilising native anchors - give an `id` to an `a`-element (`link_to` yields it), use `window.location.hash` to get `#`-part of url etc.

Comment: `data-get-url-path="#about"` isn't that what the `id` attribute is for?

Comment: @max you're correct, did not see that because of scrolling, edited

Comment: @max most probably it's X-Y problem here

Answer (score 0):

Trying to do this server side is a fools errand since the hash segment of a URL is not sent by browsers. But if I have understood you correctly and you just want to add a class to links that match the hash you can just do it with:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  if (window.location.hash) {
    document.querySelectorAll('a.nav-link[href="#%"]'.replace('%', window.location.hash))
            .forEach(function(link){
               link.classList.add('active');
            });
  }
});
```